# rails auto login after email account validation with restful_authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, restful-authentication, email-validation, autologin

I am searching for a way to auto login a user when he validates his account with a link into the email.
I can't use the authenticate method because I don't have acces to the user password.

If anyone has a solution I would be happy to know it.
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Devise and Devise Invitable gems.

https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable

Technically you are not inviting someone but what you can do is then do

```
User.invite("some-guy@example.com")
```

This will create tokens that allow them to login. Once they click the link it will direct them to edit their credentials.